# The html file doesn't show the png image

Tags: html, png

I sourced the image on VS code and when I previewed the code I can see the image, however when I open the html file the image is broken.

```
<img src="./birthday project screenshot.png" height="200"/>
```

[location of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGqjf.png)

Any idea what the issue is here?

I resaved the file, retyped the code and watch side by side on the show preview panel. Everything looks fine within VS code, once I save the work and open the index.html file it does not show the image for some reason.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

100% something wrong with either :

- The path you gave in HTML
- Where the index.html file is (assuming you are launching it locally)

*It's pretty much impossible to know without actually seeing your code*

Comment: The "path name is wrong" answer is true for this asked question here on SO and all over the internet which seems to get asked every hour.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespaces in your filename are causing the issue.
Either remove them
or replace them with '-' or '_'